# Remove the HTTP_ prefix in Rails headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actiondispatch

Any request sent to a Rails controller gets an `HTTP_` prefixed to it, as that's appended by `ActionDispatch::HTTP.Headers`. Is there a way to prevent that (without overriding `ActionDispatch::HTTP`, so that I can use my custom headers, as is and use those as keys for `headers.@env`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. That's how the `ActionDispatch::Http::Headers` class is designed to normalize the headers.

```
private

def env_name(key)
  key = key.to_s
  if key =~ HTTP_HEADER
    key = key.upcase.tr('-', '_')
    key = "HTTP_" + key unless CGI_VARIABLES.include?(key)
  end
  key
end
```

You can still use your custom headers. You just need to reference them as `HTTP_X_FOO` instead of `x-foo`.

Comment: Yes, I've already seen how it does sets @env, which now needs the `HTTP_X_FOO` to get that header, and I'm forced to have to use those as keys while passing it as a hash. The intention was to avoid having to do that.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's not possible if you are using the Rails stack.